# Ошибка sql запроса (YII)

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, помогите разобраться с ошибкой , периодически начала выпадать ошибка на сайте, повторить ошибку не получается так как через минут 5 ошибка пропадает сама собой и нужно понять в корне что ему не нравиться или где копать ?

```
CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1)) OR (order_global=1)) AND (order_subject_knowledge IN (2,9,10,366,367,368,369' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `crm_orders` `t` WHERE `t`.`order_type`=:yp0 AND (((order_city IN (1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,11,15,24,29,7,8,10,14,17,19,33,34,37,1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,1,4,9,18,21,22,28,31,36,39,43,45,2,6,23,26,27,32,38,44,12,13,16,20,25,30,35,40,41,42,,1)) OR (order_global=1)) AND (order_subject_knowledge IN (2,9,10,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,428,6,7,8,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,424,425,427,12,13,14,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,16,17,18,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365))). Bound with :yp0=1
```

скрин http://prntscr.com/itqhwm

заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: вы не хотите сделать это перечисление `IN` с помощью подзапроса то, или джоайните таблицы? откуда вы берете эти значения? они там с повторами даже

Comment: обратите внимание на `5,40,41,42,___где тут число?____,1)` про это и говорит вам текст ошибки

Comment: --teran-- это чужой проект там запрос в запросе очень сложно разобраться поэтому не лезу в корень

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проверить [онлайн-валидатором](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) ваш SQL запрос, то ошибка будет хорошо видна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при чем тут какой-то онлайн валидатор, если сообщение об ошибке, указанное автором в вопросе говорит то же самое, слово в слово причем.

Comment: Не нравится - не пользуйтесь :-Р